# @Transactional annotation with spring and getting current co

Tags: spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I have a method which has a UPDATE query and a select query. I annotated the method with @Transactional for the below use case.

For concurrent executions - if two users are updating the same table ,I need the update and select query to be run as a unit

If not using @Transactional , I am using jdbc template and i am trying to get the current connection set auto commit to false and commit to true at the end of the method

Issue 1:

Update is getting commited immediately after the statement is executed

Issue 2:

With jdbc template , unable to get the current connection used for transaction .

I have tried the below two ways to get the current connection , but it seems to be a new connection from the pool

1.Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(template.getDataSource());
2.Connection con=template.getDataSource().getConnection();

Application deployed in WebLogic Server using using java configuration , created bean for jdbc template , datasource and transaction management and used autowiring

```
@Transactional
    public Integer getNextId(String tablename) {

        Integer nextId = null;
        int swId = template.update("update " + tablename + " set swId = swId + 1");
        //int swId1 = template.update("update " + tablename + " set swId = swId + 1");

        if (swId == 1) {
            nextId = template.queryForObject("select swId from " + tablename,
                    int.class);
        }

        return nextId;
    }
}

@Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(dsnName);
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return dataSourceTransactionManager;
    }
    @Scope("prototype")
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate template(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return template;
    }
```

Expected results.
Commit should happen after all the statements in the method is executed
jdbc template need to get the active connection sed for current transaction

Comment: Why are all your beans prototypes? You don't want a brand new DataSource every time you ask for one. Same for the other beans. And how can you know that the commit is done after the update statement is executed?

Comment: when were restarting Weblogic and upon subsequent deployment , it was throwing the error JNDI name not found . So having the scope as prototype fixed the issue . Our application is deployed in Weblogic . Please suggest if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: I was in the debug mode after each of the statement is executed and checking the database if the record is updated and it was after each statement.